# GXT rtl align button icon

Tags: internationalization, vertical-alignment, gxt

I changed an existing project from gxt to gxt-trl.
I did everything according to the [instruction](http://code.google.com/p/gxt-rtl/wiki/GettingStartedg) (changed the html files and resource)
But now in all the buttons and menus, the icon goes over the text.

i tried to use

```
setIconAlign(IconAlign.END);
```

but it doesn't seems to help

Answer (score 0):

1. What browser do you use? Does this page display correctly for you? http://gxt-rtl.appspot.com/index-rtl.html#buttons
2. Here the FillToolItem is used. Do you see this demo correctly? http://gxt-rtl.appspot.com/index-rtl.html#basictoolbar
3. Did you enable GWT locale support?

Answer (score 0):

it should be :

```
setIconAlign(IconAlign.RIGHT);
```